# Use like in MongoDB

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to write a query in mongo previously I have written in MySQL
I'm trying to implement a search on multiple fields using the query

```
collection = get_connection(settings.DATABASE_NAME, settings.FARM_COLLECTION)
    result = list(collection.find(
        {'$or': [{'farm_name': "Test_Farm_26"}]}
    ).limit(filter['limit']).skip(filter['skip']))
    print(result)
```

then I am getting this output

```
[{'_id': ObjectId('6331920021a8c44f7e95ea4e'), 'farm_id': 1, 'farm_acreage': 50, 'farm_name': 'Test_Farm_26', 'assignee_id': 1, 'is_active': True, 'farm_location': {'lgd_state_id': 9, 'district_code': 119, 'sub_district_code': 755, 'village_code': 122028, 'lat': 27.934293908219843, 'lng': 78.0054819610702}, 'area_latest_id': 1, 'zone_latest_id': 0, 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 26, 11, 50, 24, 138000), 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 26, 11, 59, 50, 289000), 'created_by_id': 0, 'updated_by_id': 0, 'farm_area': [{'area_id': 1, 'area_acerage': 3, 'area_structure_type': 'polyhouse'}], 'farm_area_count': 1}]
```

as you see that the column name "farm_name" search filter is working when I am passing its total value
but when I am giving its half value and trying to use the LIKE statement in MongoDB

I'm getting a blank list as an output

```
    collection = get_connection(settings.DATABASE_NAME, settings.FARM_COLLECTION)
    result = list(collection.find(
        {'$or': [{'farm_name': "/26/"}]}
    ).limit(filter['limit']).skip(filter['skip']))
    print(result)
```

I am also other methods also getting the result

like INPUT

```
filter['search'] = "test_farm_26"

result = list(collection.aggregate([{"$match": {
        "$or": [{"farm_name": {"$regex": f'^{filter["search"]}$', '$options': 'i'}}]}}]))
```

OUTPUT

```
[{'_id': ObjectId('6331920021a8c44f7e95ea4e'), 'farm_id': 1, 'farm_acreage': 50, 'farm_name': 'Test_Farm_26', 'assignee_id': 1, 'is_active': True, 'farm_location': {'lgd_state_id': 9, 'district_code': 119, 'sub_district_code': 755, 'village_code': 122028, 'lat': 27.934293908219843, 'lng': 78.0054819610702}, 'area_latest_id': 1, 'zone_latest_id': 0, 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 26, 11, 50, 24, 138000), 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 26, 11, 59, 50, 289000), 'created_by_id': 0, 'updated_by_id': 0, 'farm_area': [{'area_id': 1, 'area_acerage': 3, 'area_structure_type': 'polyhouse'}], 'farm_area_count': 1}]
```

even case-sensitive is working fine
but then pass the partial value then I could not get the output

INPUT

```
filter['search'] = "26"

result = list(collection.aggregate([{"$match": {
        "$or": [{"farm_name": {"$regex": f'^{filter["search"]}$', '$options': 'i'}}]}}]))
```

OUTUT

```
[]
```

Comment: Either take away the quotation marks or nest it inside of `$regex`.  Right now you're asking for an exact string that contains the slashes and everything. General syntax options are noted in [the first two code blocks here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#definition)

Comment: I have tried using the /^26/ inside regex it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments and the edit, it looks like you are pretty close at this point after moving from an exact string match to a regex approach.

Your remaining issue is that the string `test_farm_26` is not matching the regex `/^26/i`. This has nothing to do with MongoDB directly. Rather, this is directly related to the definition of the regex. You have prepended the `^` character to the regex and that character matches the start of the string. So your regex will *only* match a string that *starts with* `26`. The string `test_farm_26` does not start with that hence it is not matching. You can see that demonstrated in [this example on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gkQJYt/2).

Resolving this requires simply changing your regex. Perhaps the most straightforward is just to drop the `^` character and make your regex `/26/` instead (as demonstrated in [this example](https://regex101.com/r/gkQJYt/3)). If instead you wanted the strings to *end* with `26` then the regex should be `/26$`. So your desired query might look something like this:

```
db.collection.find({
  farm_name: {
    "$regex": "26$",
    "$options": "i"
  }
})
```

You can see a demonstration of that query [in this mongoplayground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dCKgX4XhopE).